# Use case of dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

In many places you can read that `dynamic_cast` means "bad design". But I cannot find any article with appropriate usage (showing good design, not just "how to use").

I'm writing a board game with a board and **many different types of cards described with many attributes** (some cards can be put on the board). So I decided to break it down to the following classes/interfaces:

```
class Card {};
class BoardCard : public Card {};
class ActionCard : public Card {};
// Other types of cards - but two are enough
class Deck {
    Card* draw_card();
};
class Player {
    void add_card(Card* card);
    Card const* get_card();
};
class Board {
    void put_card(BoardCard const*);
};
```

Some guys suggested that I should use only one class describing a card. But I would mean many mutually excluding attributes. And in the case of the Board class' `put_card(BoardCard const&)` - it is a part of the interface that I cannot put any card on the board. If I had only one type of card I would have to check it inside the method.

I see the flow like the following:

- a **generic** card is in the deck (it's not important what its type is)
- a **generic** card is drawn from the deck and given to a player (the same as above)
- if a player chosen a **BoardCard** then it can be put on the board

So I use `dynamic_cast` before putting a card on the board. I think that using some virtual method is out of the question in this case (additionally I wouldn't make any sense to add some action about board to every card).

So my question is: What have I designed badly? How could I avoid `dynamic_cast`? Using some type attribute and `if`s would be a better solution...?

P.S.
Any source treating about `dynamic_cast` usage in the context of design is more than appreciated.

Comment: Usage of `dyamic_cast` is most often an indicator of bad design. Consider using an interface instead.

Comment: @TheDude No offense but that's what I can read all over the place. It's like a bot quote. But what interface makes sense here? I can't see...

Comment: `bool can_put_on_board() const`?

Comment: What is the question? Design and architecture are often off-topic for SO. If you have a working code then please consider Code Review SE instead. Avoid cross posting if you go there.

Comment: @Ron There are 3 questions but all about the same. Is it the one of cases where `dynamic_cast` is alright? If no then what?

Comment: @user2146414 Academia likes the `dynamic_cast`. Industry - not so much.

Comment: @Ron Do you mean: "From academic point of view it would be a valid use case of `dynamic_cast` (=not overusing)"?

Comment: @user2146414 Using `dynamic_cast` is a sign of code smell. If you have proper polymorphic behavior of your classes then why would you want to use the `dynamic_cast` at all? Just because it is there does not mean you have to use it aka YAGNI. The only cast you should probably concern yourself with is the `static_cast`. Avoid casting.

Comment: If you want an example of `dynamic_cast` used in a positive way, [uncle Bob used it to modify the visitor design pattern](http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/OOT/Design-Principles/acv.pdf). An acyclic visitor allows visitable classes to be added without rebuilding all of the existing visitors.

Comment: I don't think sound designs really start out with `dynamic_cast`. Like all casts in C++, it's more like patches that you apply to your code at a later development step, when you interface with legacy code or need a quick workaround without refactoring everything.

Comment: "what interface makes sense here" Where's "here"? Show some actual code.

Comment: @StoryTeller *acyclic visitor* that's infrastructure, not application logic. You normally write it once, or use a ready made library, and it stays put while your application expands and adds new classes. It could well be a part of the standard library.

Comment: Why exactly is a virtual method out of the question?

Comment: StackOverflow has pondered on the use of dynamic_cast quite a few times already. The Bounty is giving everyone a free ride but please check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Comment: One of my colleagues sent me an article that gives a different perspective (in 5th part) to the problem (quite long but worth reading in my opinion): https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Answer (score 15):

Yes, `dynamic_cast` is a code smell, but so is adding functions that try to make it look like you have a good polymorphic interface but are actually equal to a `dynamic_cast` i.e. stuff like `can_put_on_board`. I'd go as far as to say that `can_put_on_board` is worse - you're duplicating code otherwise implemented by `dynamic_cast` and cluttering the interface.

As with all code smells, they should make you wary and they don't necessarily mean that your code is bad. This all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

If you're implementing a board game that will have 5k lines of code, two categories of cards, then anything that works is fine. If you're designing something larger, extensible and possibly allowing for cards being created by non-programmers (whether it's an actual need or you're doing it for research) then this probably won't do.

Assuming the latter, let's look at some alternatives.

You could put the onus of applying the card properly to the card, instead of some external code. E.g. add a `play(Context& c)` function to the card (the `Context` being a means to access the board and whatever may be necessary). A board card would know that it may only be applied to a board and a cast would not be necessary.

I would entirely give up using inheritance however. One of its many issues is how it introduces a categorisation of all cards. Let me give you an example:

- you introduce `BoardCard` and `ActionCard` putting all cards in these two buckets;
- you then decide that you want to have a card that can be used in two ways, either as an `Action` or a `Board` card;
- let's say you solved the issue (through multiple-inheritance, a `BoardActionCard` type, or any different way);
- you then decide you want to have card colours (as in MtG) - how do you do this? Do you create `RedBoardCard`, `BlueBoardCard`, `RedActionCard` etc?

Other examples of why inheritance should be avoided and how to achieve runtime polymorphism otherwise you may want to watch Sean Parent's excellent ["Inheritance is the Base Class of Evil" talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil). A promising looking library that implements this sort of polymorphism is [dyno](https://github.com/ldionne/dyno), I have not tried it out yet though.

A possible solution might be:

```
class Card final {
public:
    template <class T>
    Card(T model) :
        model_(std::make_shared<Model<T>>(std::move(model)))
    {}

    void play(Context& c) const {
        model_->play(c);
    }

    // ... any other functions that can be performed on a card

private:

    class Context {
    public:
        virtual ~Context() = default;
        virtual void play(Context& c) const = 0;
    };

    template <class T>
    class Model : public Context {
    public:
        void play(Context& c) const override {
            play(model_, c);

            // or

            model_.play(c);

            // depending on what contract you want to have with implementers
        }
    private:
        T model_;
    };

    std::shared_ptr<const Context> model_;

};
```

Then you can either create classes per card type:

```
class Goblin final {
    void play(Context& c) const {
        // apply effects of card, e.g. take c.board() and put the card there
    }
};
```

Or implement behaviours for different categories, e.g. have a

```
template <class T>
void play(const T& card, Context& c);
```

template and then use enable_if to handle it for different categories:

```
template <class T, class = std::enable_if<IsBoardCard_v<T>>
void play(const T& card, Context& c) {
    c.board().add(Card(card));
}
```

where:

```
template <class T>
struct IsBoardCard {
    static constexpr auto value = T::IS_BOARD_CARD;
};

template <class T>
using IsBoardCard_v = IsBoardCard<T>::value;
```

then defining your `Goblin` as:

```
class Goblin final {
public:
    static constexpr auto IS_BOARD_CARD = true;
    static constexpr auto COLOR = Color::RED;
    static constexpr auto SUPERMAGIC = true;
};
```

which would allow you to categorise your cards in many dimensions also leaving the possibility to entirely specialise the behaviour by implementing a different `play` function.

The example code uses std::shared_ptr to store the model, but you can definitely do something smarter here. I like to use a static-sized storage and only allow Ts of a certain maximum size and alignment to be used. Alternatively you could use a std::unique_ptr (which would disable copying though) or a variant leveraging small-size optimisation.

Comment: I think you have a small error that may confuse some people (it confused me a little).
Shouldn't `template <class T> class Model` inherit from `Context`?

Answer (score 4):

## Why not use `dynamic_cast`

`dynamic_cast` is generally disliked because it can be easily abused to completely break the abstractions used. And it is not wise to depend on specific implementations. Of course it may needed, but really rarely, so nearly everyone takes a rule of thumb - probably you should not use it. It's a code smell that may imply that you should rethink Your abstractions because they may be not the ones needed in Your domain. Maybe in Your game the `Board` should not have `put_card` method - maybe instead card should have method `play(const PlaySpace *)` where `Board` implements `PlaySpace` or something like that. Even [CppCoreGuidelines discourage using `dynamic_cast` in most cases](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-dynamic_cast).

## When use

Generally few people ever have problems like this but I came across it multiple times already. The problem is called **Double (or Multiple) Dispatch**. Here is pretty old, but quite relevant article about double dispatch (mind the prehistoric `auto_ptr`):
http://www.drdobbs.com/double-dispatch-revisited/184405527

Also Scott Meyers in one of his books wrote something about building double dispatch matrix with `dynamic_cast`. But, all in all, these `dynamic_cast`s are 'hidden` inside this matrix - users don't know what kind of magic happens inside.

Noteworthy - multiple dispatch is also considered code smell :-).

## Reasonable alternative

Check out the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It can be used as replace for `dynamic_cast` but it is also some kind of code smell.

I generally recommend using `dynamic_cast` and visitor as a last resort tools for design problems as they break abstraction which increases complexity.

Answer (score 3):

You could apply the principles behind [Microsoft's COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363(v=vs.85).aspx) and provide a series of *interfaces*, with each interface describing a set of related behaviors. In COM you determine if a specific interface is available by calling `QueryInterface`, but in modern C++ `dynamic_cast` works similarly and is more efficient.

```
class Card {
    virtual void ~Card() {} // must have at least one virtual method for dynamic_cast
};
struct IBoardCard {
    virtual void put_card(Board* board);
};
class BoardCard : public Card, public IBoardCard {};
class ActionCard : public Card {};
// Other types of cards - but two are enough
class Deck {
    Card* draw_card();
};
class Player {
    void add_card(Card* card);
    Card const* get_card();
};
class Board {
    void put_card(Card const* card) {
        const IBoardCard *p = dynamic_cast<const IBoardCard*>(card);
        if (p != null) p->put_card(this);
};
```

That may be a bad example, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: That looks similar to what I thought about. But I believe that Board should take `IBoardCard` and this `if` should be outside. Something like: Let a player choose a card. If it's a board card (`dynamic_cast` here) then let him choose a place to put and then put.

Comment: @user2146414 that probably makes more sense, but I framed my answer in the context of the code you gave rather than the code you didn't.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the two types of cards are quite different. The things a board card and an action card can do are mutually exclusive, and the common thing is just that they can be drawn from the deck. Moreover, that's not a thing a *card* does, it's a player / deck action.

**If this is true**, a question one should ask is **whether they should really descend from a common type**, `Card`. An alternative design would be that of a **tagged union**: let `Card` instead be a `std::variant<BoardCard, ActionCard...>`, and *contain* an instance of the appropriate type. When deciding what to do with the card, you use a `switch` on the `index()` and then `std::get<>` only the appropriate type. This way you don't need *any* `*_cast` operator, and get a complete freedom of what methods (neither of which would make sense for the other types) each type of card supports.

If it's only *almost* true but not for all types, you can variate slightly: only group together those types of cards that can sensibly be superclassed, and put the set of those common types into the `variant`.

Answer (score 1):

I always found the usage of a cast a code smell, and in my experience, the 90% of the time the cast was due to bad design. 
I saw usage of dynamic_cast in some time-critical application where it was providing more performance improvement than inherit from multiple interfaces or retrieving an enumeration of some kind from the object (like a type). So the code smelt, but the usage of the dynamic cast was worth it in that case.

That said, I will avoid dynamic cast in your case as well as multiple inheritances from different interfaces.

Before reaching my solution, your description sounds like there are a lot of details omitted about the behavior of the cards or the consequence they have on the board
and the game itself. I used that as a further constraint, trying to keep thing boxed and maintainable.

I would go for a composition instead of an inheritance. It will provide you evenly the chance of using the card as a 'factory':

- it can spawn more game modifiers - something to be applied to the board, and one to a specific enemy
- the card can be reused - the card could stays in the hands of the player and the effect on the game is detached from it (there is no 1-1 binding between cards and effects)
- the card itself can sit back on the deck, while the effects of what it did are still alive on the board.
- a card can have a representation (drawing methods) and react to the touch in a way, where instead the BoardElement can be evenly a 3d miniature with animation

See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance for further details]. I'd like to quote: 
Composition also provides a more stable business domain in the long term as it is less prone to the quirks of the family members.In other words, it is better to compose what an object can do (HAS - A) than extend what it is(IS - A).[1]

A BoardCard/Element can be something like this:

```
//the card placed on the board.
class BoardElement {
public:
  BoardElement() {}
  virtual ~BoardElement() {};

  //up to you if you want to add a read() methods to read data from the card description (XML / JSON / binary data)
  // but that should not be part of the interface. Talking about a potential "Wizard", it's probably more related to the WizardCard - WizardElement relation/implementation

  //some helpful methods:
  // to be called by the board when placed
  virtual void OnBoard() {}
  virtual void Frame(const float time) { /*do something time based*/ }
  virtual void Draw() {}
  // to be called by the board when removed
  virtual void RemovedFromBoard() {}
};
```

the Card could represent something to be used in a deck or in the user's hands, I'll add an interface of that kind

```
class Card {
public:
  Card() {}
  virtual ~Card() {}

  //that will be invoked by the user in order to provide something to the Board, or NULL if nothing should be added.
  virtual std::shared_ptr<BoardElement*> getBoardElement() { return nullptr; }

  virtual void Frame(const float time) { /*do something time based*/ }
  virtual void Draw() {}

  //usefull to handle resources or internal states
  virtual void OnUserHands() {}
  virtual void Dropped() {}
};
```

I'd like to add that this pattern allows many tricks inside the `getBoardElement()` method, from acting as a factory (so something should be spawned with its own lifetime),
returning an `Card` data member such as a `std:shared_ptr<BoardElement> wizard3D;` (as example), create a binding between the `Card` and the `BoardElement` as for:

```
class WizardBoardElement : public BoardElement {
public:
  WizardBoardElement(const Card* owner);

  // other members omitted ...
};
```

The binding can be useful in order to read some configuration data or whatever...

So inheritance from `Card` and from `BoardElement` will be used to implement the features exposed by the base classes and not for providing other methods that can be reached only through a `dynamic_cast`.

For completeness:

```
class Player {
  void add(Card* card) {
    //..
    card->OnUserHands();
    //..
  }

  void useCard(Card* card) {
    //..

    //someway he's got to retrieve the board...
    getBoard()->add(card->getBoardElement());

    //..
  }

  Card const* get_card();
};

class Board {
  void add(BoardElement* el) {
    //..
    el->OnBoard();
    //..
  }
};
```

In that way, we have no dynamic_cast, Player and board do simple things without knowing about the inner details of the card they are handled, providing good separations between the different objects and increasing maintainability.

Talking about the `ActionCard`, and about "effects" that may be applied to other players or your avatar, we can think about having a method like:

```
enum EffectTarget {
  MySelf,      //a player on itself, an enemy on itself
  MainPlayer,
  Opponents,
  StrongOpponents

  //....
};

class Effect {
public:
  //...
  virtual void Do(Target* target) = 0;
  //...
};

class Card {
public:
  //...
  struct Modifiers {
    EffectTarget eTarget;
    std::shared_ptr<Effect> effect;
  };

  virtual std::vector<Modifiers> getModifiers() { /*...*/ }

  //...
};

class Player : public Target {
public: 

  void useCard(Card* card) {
    //..

    //someway he's got to retrieve the board...
    getBoard()->add(card->getBoardElement());

    auto modifiers = card->getModifiers();
    for each (auto modifier in modifiers)
    {
      //this method is supposed to look at the board, at the player and retrieve the instance of the target 
      Target* target = getTarget(modifier.eTarget);
      modifier.effect->Do(target);
    }

    //..
  }

};
```

That's another example of the same pattern to apply the effects from the card, avoiding the cards to know details about the board and it's status, who is playing the card, and keep the code in `Player` pretty simple.

Hope this may help,
Have a nice day,
Stefano.

Answer (score 0):

> What have I designed badly?

The problem is that you always need to extend that code whenever a new type of `Card` is introduced.

> How could I avoid dynamic_cast?

The usual way to avoid that is to use interfaces (i.e. pure abstract classes):

```
struct ICard {
   virtual bool can_put_on_board() = 0;
   virtual ~ICard() {}
};

class BoardCard : public ICard {
public:
    bool can_put_on_board() { return true; };
};

class ActionCard : public ICard {
public:
    bool can_put_on_board() { return false; };
};
```

This way you can simply use a reference or pointer to `ICard` and check, if the actual type it holds can be put on the `Board`.

---

> But I cannot find any article with appropriate usage (showing good design, not just "how to use").

In general I'd say there aren't any good, real life use cases for dynamic cast.

Sometimes I have used it in debug code for CRTP realizations like

```
template<typename Derived> 
class Base {
public:
    void foo() {
#ifndef _DEBUG     
      static_cast<Derived&>(*this).doBar();
#else
      // may throw in debug mode if something is wrong with Derived
      // not properly implementing the CRTP
      dynamic_cast<Derived&>(*this).doBar();
#endif
    }
};
```

Comment: This way I have to supply `can_put_` for every use case. Is it really clean way? If a new card appears then I need to add a new `can_put...` to base class and to every derived class.

Comment: @user2146414 _"This way I have to supply can_put_ for every use case"_ I don't get what you mean. Anyways that's the cleanest way I know of. I'd avoid `dynamic_cast` just like hell.

Comment: You don't have to add a new can_put_ to ICard if a new derived card type appears. ICard::can_put_ is pure virtual. You do have to implement the derived can_put method for the new card type, but you'd have to do that anyway.

Comment: But using `dynamic_cast` and adding a new type of card I do not have to change my code. Just to add a new `dynaimc_cast` if needed. And `Card` does not have to know how it will be used (and that has place in the case of `can_put_on_board` - I inject some information about board into the `ICard`)

Comment: @user2146414 _"I do not have to change my code"_ That's a quite silly (sorry no offense) argument. Refactoring code to better design is daily bread and butter.

Comment: OK we are getting beyond the scope of the question, but if whether or not a card can be placed depends on attributes external to the card (e.g state of the board) I don't see how use of dynamic_cast leads to a cleaner design than using an interface.

Comment: @TheDude I didn't mean refactor. I meant adding a card that `can_put_befor_player`. It would need to add the method to _every_ card. Although only a newly added card is involved.

Comment: @user2146414 You should probably give a better and more concise example in your question then.

Comment: @paisanco `dynamic_cast` is only used in (let's say) one place. For example ActionCard does not know about board, the same about BlockCard, HealingCard etc. I find it "clearer".

Comment: @user2146414 As mentioned, show a better example of your supposedly _clean design_ in your question, instead of arguing in comments. That's not useful for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I would end up with something like this (compiled with clang 5.0 with -std=c++17). I'm couroius about your comments. So whenever I want to handle different types of Cards I need to instantiate a dispatcher and supply methods with proper signatures.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>


template <class T, class... Args>
struct any_abstract {
    static bool constexpr value = std::is_abstract<T>::value || any_abstract<Args...>::value;
};


template <class T>
struct any_abstract<T> {
    static bool constexpr value = std::is_abstract<T>::value;
};


template <class T, class... Args>
struct StaticDispatcherImpl {
    template <class P, class U>
    static void dispatch(P* ptr, U* object) {
        if (typeid(*object) == typeid(T)) {
            ptr->do_dispatch(*static_cast<T*>(object));
            return;
        }

        if constexpr (sizeof...(Args)) {
            StaticDispatcherImpl<Args...>::dispatch(ptr, object);
        }
    }
};


template <class Derived, class... Args>
struct StaticDispatcher {
    static_assert(not any_abstract<Args...>::value);

    template <class U>
    void dispatch(U* object) {
        if (object) {
            StaticDispatcherImpl<Args...>::dispatch(static_cast<Derived *>(this), object);
        }
    }
};


struct Card {
    virtual ~Card() {}
};
struct BoardCard : Card {};
struct ActionCard : Card {};


struct Board {
    void put_card(BoardCard const& card, int const row, int const column) {
        std::cout << "Putting card on " << row << " " << column << std::endl;
    }
};


struct UI : StaticDispatcher<UI, BoardCard, ActionCard> {
    void do_dispatch(BoardCard const& card) {
        std::cout << "Get row to put: ";
        int row;
        std::cin >> row;

        std::cout << "Get row to put:";
        int column;
        std::cin >> column;

        board.put_card(card, row, column);
    }

    void do_dispatch(ActionCard& card) {
        std::cout << "Handling action card" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    Board board;
};


struct Game {};


int main(int, char**) {
    Card* card;
    ActionCard ac;
    BoardCard bc;

    UI ui;

    card = &ac;
    ui.dispatch(card);

    card = &bc;
    ui.dispatch(card);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a more complicated way of achieving the same what can be done using `std::variant`

Comment: You're right. Despite what I wrote I ended up with `std::variant` :)

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see why you wouldn't use virtual methods, I'm just gonna present, how I would do it. First I have the `ICard` interface for all cards. Then I would distinguish, between the card types (i.e. BoardCard and ActionCard and whatever cards you have). And All the cards inherit from either one of the card types.

```
class ICard {
    virtual void put_card(Board* board) = 0;
    virtual void accept(CardVisitor& visitor) = 0; // See later, visitor pattern
}

class ActionCard : public ICard {
    void put_card(Board* board) final {
        // std::cout << "You can't put Action Cards on the board << std::endl;
        // Or just do nothing, if the decision of putting the card on the board
        // is not up to the user
    }
}

class BoardCard : public ICard {
    void put_card(Board* board) final {
        // Whatever implementation puts the card on the board, mb something like:
        board->place_card_on_board(this);
    }
}

class SomeBoardCard : public BoardCard {
    void accept(CardVisitor& visitor) final { // visitor pattern
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
    void print_information(); // see BaseCardVisitor in the next code section
}
class SomeActionCard : public ActionCard {
    void accept(CardVisitor& visitor) final { // visitor pattern
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
    void print_information(); // see BaseCardVisitor
}

class Board {
    void put_card(ICard* const card) {
         card->put_card(this);
    }

    void place_card_on_board(BoardCard* card) {
         // place it on the board
    }
}
```

I guess the user has to know somehow what card he has drawn, so for that I would implement the visitor pattern. You could also place the `accept`-method, which I placed in the most derived classes/cards, in the card types (BoardCard, ActionCard), depeneding on where you want to draw the line on what information shall be given to the user.

```
template <class T>
class BaseCardVisitor {
    void visit(T* card) {
        card->print_information();
    }
}

class CardVisitor : public BaseCardVisitor<SomeBoardCard>,
                    public BaseCardVisitor<SomeActionCard> {

}

class Player {
    void add_card(ICard* card);
    ICard const* get_card();

    void what_is_this_card(ICard* card) {
          card->accept(visitor);
    }

    private:
      CardVisitor visitor;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hardly a complete answer but just wanted to pitch in with an answer similar to `Mark Ransom`'s but just very generally speaking, I've found downcasting to be useful in cases where duck typing is really useful. There can be certain architectures where it is very useful to do things like this:

```
for each object in scene:
{
     if object can fly:
          make object fly
}
```

Or:

```
for each object in scene that can fly:
     make object fly
```

COM allows this type of thing somewhat like so:

```
for each object in scene:
{
     // Request to retrieve a flyable interface from
     // the object.
     IFlyable* flyable = object.query_interface<IFlyable>();

     // If the object provides such an interface, make
     // it fly.
     if (flyable)
          flyable->fly();
}
```

Or:

```
for each flyable in scene.query<IFlyable>:
     flyable->fly();
```

This implies a cast of some form somewhere in the centralized code to query and obtain interfaces (ex: from `IUnknown` to `IFlyable`). In such cases, a dynamic cast checking run-time type information is the safest type of cast available. First there might be a general check to see if an object provides the interface that doesn't involve casting. If it doesn't, this `query_interface` function might return a null pointer or some type of null handle/reference. If it does, then using a `dynamic_cast` against RTTI is the safest thing to do to fetch the actual pointer to the generic interface (ex: `IInterface*`) and return `IFlyable*` to the client.

Another example is entity-component systems. In that case instead of querying abstract interfaces, we retrieve concrete components (data):

```
Flight System:
for each object in scene:
{
     if object.has<Wings>():
          make object fly using object.get<Wings>()
}
```

Or:

```
for each wings in scene.query<Wings>()
     make wings fly
```

... something to this effect, and that also implies casting somewhere.

[image]

For my domain (VFX, which is somewhat similar to gaming in terms of application and scene state), I've found this type of ECS architecture to be the easiest to maintain. I can only speak from personal experience, but I've been around for a long time and have faced many different architectures. COM is now the most popular style of architecture in VFX and I used to work on a commercial VFX application used widely in films and games and archviz and so forth which used a COM architecture, but I've found ECS as popular in game engines even easier to maintain than COM for my particular case*.

> - One of the reasons I find ECS so much easier is because the bulk of the systems in this domain like `PhysicsSystem`, `RenderingSystem`, `AnimationSystem`, etc. boil down to just data transformers and the ECS model just fits beautifully for that purpose without abstractions getting in the way. With COM in this domain, the number of subtypes implementing an interface like a motion interface like `IMotion` might be in the hundreds (ex: a `PointLight` which implements `IMotion` along with 5 other interfaces), requiring hundreds of classes implementing different combinations of COM interfaces to maintain individually. With the ECS, it uses a composition model over inheritance, and reduces those hundreds of classes down to just a couple dozen simple component `structs` which can be combined in endless ways by the entities that compose them, and only a handful of systems have to provide behavior: everything else is just data which the systems loop through as input to then provide some output.

Between legacy codebases that used a bunch of global variables and brute force coding (ex: sprinkling conditionals all over the place instead of using polymorphism), deep inheritance hierarchies, COM, and ECS, in terms of maintainability for my particular domain, I'd say `ECS > COM`, while deep inheritance hierarchies and brute force coding with global variables all over the place were both incredibly hard to maintain (OOP using deep inheritance with protected data fields is almost as hard to reason about in terms of maintaining invariants as a boatload of global variables IMO, but further can invite the most nightmarish cascading changes spilling across entire hierarchies if designs need to change -- at least the brute force legacy codebase didn't have the cascading problem since it was barely reusing any code to begin with).

COM and ECS are somewhat similar except with COM, the dependencies flow towards central abstractions (COM interfaces provided by COM objects, like `IFlyable`). With an ECS, the dependencies flow towards central data (components provided by ECS entities, like `Wings`). At the heart of both is often the idea that we have a bunch of non-homogeneous objects (or "entities") of interest whose provided interfaces or components are not known in advance, since we're accessing them through a non-homogeneous collection (ex: a "Scene"). As a result we need to discover their capabilities at runtime when iterating through this non-homogeneous collection by either querying the collection or the objects individually to see what they provide.

Either way, both involve some type of centralized casting to retrieve either an interface or a component from an entity, and if we have to downcast, then a `dynamic_cast` is at least the safest way to do that which involves runtime type checking to make sure the cast is valid. And with both ECS and COM, you generally only need one line of code in the entire system which performs this cast.

That said, the runtime checking does have a small cost. Typically if `dynamic_cast` is used in COM and ECS architectures, it's done in a way so that a `std::bad_cast` should never be thrown and/or that `dynamic_cast` itself never returns `nullptr` (the `dynamic_cast` is just a sanity check to make sure there are no internal programmer errors, not as a way to determine if an object inherits a type). Another type of runtime check is made to avoid that (ex: just once for an entire query in an ECS when fetching all `PosAndVelocity` components to determine which component list to use which is actually homogeneous and only stores `PosAndVelocity` components). If that small runtime cost is non-negligible because you're looping over a boatload of components every frame and doing trivial work to each, then I found this snippet useful from Herb Sutter in C++ Coding Standards:

```
template<class To, class From> To checked_cast(From* from) {
    assert( dynamic_cast<To>(from) == static_cast<To>(from) && "checked_cast failed" );
    return static_cast<To>(from);
}

template<class To, class From> To checked_cast(From& from) {
    assert( dynamic_cast<To>(from) == static_cast<To>(from) && "checked_cast failed" );
    return static_cast<To>(from);
}
```

It basically uses `dynamic_cast` as a sanity check for debug builds with an `assert`, and `static_cast` for release builds.